# Socket.io Chat Application Refreshes When I Send a Message

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to make a simple chat application using Node.js, socket.io, and express. However, if I click the send button in the main.jade file, the page refreshes, and no message appears. I also get this error in Firebug:

> The connection to ws://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket&sid=d_hNMPdXHed-j7LrAAAH was interrupted while the page was loading.

Main.jade

```
doctype html
html
head
    meta(charset = "UTF-8")

    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script(src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js")
    script.
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });

body    
    ul#messages
    form(action = "")
        input#m(type = "text")
        button Send
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/pesterchum');


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

www

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('app');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.sockets.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET Main page. */
router.get('/main', function(req, res) {
        res.render('main', { title: 'Main'});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the page is being reloaded because you've forgotten to wrap your client js code with `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`